# How many epic spell seeds can you know?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, epic-tier

I understand the ruling on epic spells per day, and how many epic spells know, but does the 'seed' itself count as a spell itself that takes up one of the slots? I am reading [Epic Spellcasting in the SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/spellsIntro.htm#epicSpellcasting) and I am not quite sure if it counts as a spell known or not?

I am a level 25 sorcerer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**It does not count as a spell**

Seeds are used only during the *development* part of creating an epic spell and have no effect on how many epic spells you may prepare or cast, though they are fundamental part of creating an epic spell or spells.

As far as I can tell (checking [here](http://www.d20srd.org/indexes/epicSpells.htm) and more specifically [here](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/developingEpicSpells.htm)) there's no actual 'seeds known'; seeds are not *learned*, simply *used*. With that in mind there may be a contradicting source from outside of the SRD, and certain epic prestige classes interact with specific seeds (for example, the Netherese Arcanist from the *Player's Guide to Faerun*)

Comment: +1 for answering the direct question. As a suggestion, you could extend this by explaining how seeds *are* gained/known/tracked.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, they're not! That said I expanded my answer with that information.

Comment: I understood it the same way. Seeds are mostly a way of letting the DM figure out how to set the DC, reach, and limitations of an Epic spell.

Comment: I'm guessing Seeds are the sort of thing you can just look up from the proper tomes you keep lying around the arcane laboratory you undoubtedly would need and have access to as an epic-level caster trying to make a new spell.